# Compare two ordered lists for similarity

Tags: statistics, information-theory

Assume I have two lists:

```
L1: [1,2,3,4]
L2: [1,3,2,4,5]
```

How can I compute the similarity between theses two lists?

If these two lists would be of same length, Spearman and Kendall seem to be the answer, but can this principle also extended to lists of diverging length?

Comment: Are they always ranks? Or are they arbitrary lists?

Comment: Are they numerical lists?

Comment: No, they are strings. But I may either perform a SimHash to obtain a number or make function I(string)-->int

Answer (score 2):

Bioinformatics and language analysis fields have similar problems. You can use various sequence kernels (see papers by Corinna Cortes for example) and [edit distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a promising algorithm to measure similarity of a list is to use Spearman footrule distance http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Similarity/FootruleDistance.html, or more involved and taking order into account, discounted cumulative gain, DCG, https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/NormalizedDiscountedCumulativeGain .

A very good resource to that topic is

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.2691.pdf

and

http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/slides/www10-metrics.pdf