# Information retrieval metrics for evaluating observations retrieved from KNN similar to mAP, but considering instances and not labels

Tags: python, performance, knn, information-retrieval

I want to evaluate a retrieval system's performance, and **mAP** is the most popular metric because it evaluates relevant versus irrelevant documents. The relevance or irrelevance criterion is based on the query label (if the query label is the same as the returned element it is relevant, otherwise irrelevant).

```
def average_precision(relevant_indices):
    precision_sum = 0.0
    num_relevant = 0

    for i, is_relevant in enumerate(relevant_indices, 1):
        if is_relevant:
            num_relevant += 1
            precision_sum += num_relevant / i

    if num_relevant == 0:
        return 0.0

    return precision_sum / num_relevant



def mean_average_precision(list_of_relevant_indices):
    total_ap = 0.0

    for relevant_indices in list_of_relevant_indices:
        ap = average_precision(relevant_indices)
        total_ap += ap

    return total_ap / len(list_of_relevant_indices)
```

I want to go deeper and I want to change the relevance and irrelevance criteria: for each observation in my test set used to measure system performance, I have a list of nearest observations as ground truth. My system relying on kNN retrieves a list of observations and I want to measure the similarity between the two lists in terms of items and locations.

Do you know any state-of-the-art metrics that do this and can you provide the code?

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288470/compare-two-ordered-lists-for-similarity) helpful. MAP@k also looks somewhat similar to what you're trying to do, though it won't take the ground truth order into account.

Comment: Thank you, it seems very usefull!!